# What is the advantage of setting a default editor for Bash?

Tags: bash, unix, editor

I understand that we can specify a default editor by setting the `EDITOR` variable. What is the advantage of setting this when we can directly specify the editor name while opening a file like `vi 1.txt` or `nano 1.txt`?

Comment: For hardcore power-users, everything is about reducing the number of keystrokes it takes to accomplish anything. I don't personally find any use from it, but I'm guessing that's what it is

Comment: How does this reduce the keystrokes?

Comment: I can't think of an example. But I do know that IPython uses that env variable for editing.

Comment: e.g. if you do a git commit it will open the $EDITOR for you to edit the comment, probably several more examples like this where a command allows you to edit something using your $EDITOR as default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One use I can think of is when you want to edit your current command line (the readline `edit-and-execute-command`, usually bound to `C-xC-e`), the editor being used is (quote from [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-edit_002dand_002dexecute_002dcommand-_0028C_002dxC_002de_0029)):

> `$VISUAL`, `$EDITOR`, and emacs as the editor, in that order.

So if you haven't set `VISUAL` and don't want to use emacs, you can have `EDITOR=vim`, for example.

Another use is `fc`, which invokes `${FCEDIT:-${EDITOR:-vi}}` to edit the last command (see [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-fc)), and maybe you don't want to use vi.

So, I'd say the purpose of `EDITOR` (and the related `FCEDIT` and `VISUAL`) is to give you the editor you want in situations where you can't specify it in a command directly.

Answer (score 1):

I set it for `less` (`man less`):

```
v      Invokes an editor to edit the current file  being  viewed.   The
       editor is taken from the environment variable VISUAL if defined,
       or EDITOR if VISUAL is not defined, or defaults to "vi" if  nei‐
       ther  VISUAL  nor EDITOR is defined.  See also the discussion of
       LESSEDIT under the section on PROMPTS below.
```

It was also related to using [`emacs` as a daemon](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsAsDaemon#toc2)